# Adding line to Customview each time when i am scroll tableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StackingCell
    let data = stack[indexPath.row]
    cell.stackDeatils = data
    cell.floorNumber_Label.text = data.floorNo
    let floorDetails = data.floorDetails!
        if floorDetails == "NA"{
        cell.floor_View.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    }
else {
        for items in floorDetails
        {

            let floorArr = items.1
            cell.floor_View.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

            //Number of Units passing value to cell
            cell.secitons = floorArr.count
            for units in floorArr {
                let unit = units.1
                let compName = unit["companyName"].string!
                if compName == "Vacant" {
                    cell.floor_View.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 94/255, green: 198/255, blue: 162/255, alpha: 1.0)

                }


                }
            }

        }

    }

    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.floor_View.bounds)
    cell.floor_View.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.floor_View.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.floor_View.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 0.5)
    cell.floor_View.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    cell.floor_View.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath
    return cell

}

CustomTableCell method for adding vertical line to TableViewCell 
var stackDeatils:StackingModel!{
    didSet
    {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       self.updateData()
      }
    }

}

func updateData(){
let unit = self.stackDeatils.isUnitsDrawn
if unit == true  {
    self.stackDeatils.isUnitsDrawn = false
    let stack_width = self.floor_View.frame.width
    let stack_height = self.floor_View.frame.height
    xCor = stack_width/CGFloat(self.secitons)
    var x = xCor

    for var i = 1;i < self.secitons; i++ {

        let line = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(x, 0, 2,stack_height))
        line.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        //print(xCor)
        self.floor_View.addSubview(line)
        x += xCor
         }
    }

else {
    print(self.stackDeatils.isUnitsDrawn)

  }

}
```

[image]